# Modify mode-compile.el to handle MS-Windows paths with imbedded blanks?

Tags: windows, ruby, emacs, compilation, elisp

Can anyone suggest a modification of mode-compile.el that will make it work better on Windows?  My specific issue is handling of path names that contain blanks.  I'm working on code in Ruby, using "GNU Emacs 22.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2008-03-26 on RELEASE" with mode-compile.el version: 2.29 (Last modified: 2006/12/01 13:52:47)

The command line generated by mode-compile.el to compile (run) my buffer a.rb is this:

c:/ruby/bin\ruby.exe -w c:/Documents and Settings/William/My Documents/src/a.rb

Which generates this error:

c:/ruby/bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- c:/Documents (LoadError)

This works just fine:

c:/ruby/bin\ruby.exe -w "c:/Documents and Settings/William/My Documents/src/a.rb"

As a work-around, I can just move my directory tree so that the path has no embedded blanks.  Looking at the code in mode-compile.el, it APPEARS that a function exists already to add the quotes, however, as I am NOT proficient in emacs-lisp, perhaps this actually does something entirely different (like just appending a nearly-empty par of double quote marks):

(if to-compile-fname
   (if mc--build-op-args
    (mc--build-output-args to-compile-fname)
      (concat " " to-compile-fname)
      )
   " "))))

mode-compile.el comes from here:
http://perso.tls.cena.fr/boubaker/distrib/mode-compile.el

Thanks in advance!

William

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this really, but it appears to me that the function `mc--shell-compile` needs to be updated. The filename of the buffer is extracted by the following lines:

```
     (shfile  (or mc--remote-pathname (buffer-file-name)
                  (error "Compilation abort: Buffer %s has no filename"
                         (buffer-name))))
```

the fix should be to quote the `buffer-file-name`:

```
     (shfile  (or mc--remote-pathname (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name)
                  (error "Compilation abort: Buffer %s has no filename"
                         (buffer-name))))
```

Can you have a try and report, please?

Cheers,
Daniel